# gtrends date misalignment in R

Tags: r, date, xts, gtrendsr

I have having some serious trouble combining a number of xts series, as there is a misalignment of dates, that I been stuck on for a good 24 hours.

I am trying to combine an xts series of weekly data with data downloaded using gtrends in R. The problem is, that the data from gtrends isn't consistently taken every 7 days, but as months change, sometime there are 6 or 8 days between observations. This stops me from combining the datasets, as the dates for some months are not aligned. I was hence hoping that someone could give me a hint as to how to either get evenly spaced google data via gtrends or how to allow leeway of a day when merging datasets (sot that the data for dates 2012-03-06 and 2012-03-07 will be combined).

See below for an examples of the misalignment:

```
merge(g.trend, Join.weekly)

2013-08-23      23          59
2013-08-30      22          77
2013-09-06      22          64
2013-09-13      21          58
2013-09-20      21          69
2013-09-27      21          90
2013-10-04      21          56
2013-10-11      21          64
2013-10-18      21          45
2013-10-25      20          43
2013-11-01      NA          76
2013-11-02      20          NA
2013-11-08      NA          77
2013-11-09      22          NA
2013-11-15      NA          59
2013-11-16      22          NA
2013-11-22      NA          71
2013-11-23      20          NA
2013-11-29      NA          70
2013-11-30      19          NA
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the queries you're running with gtrends? Are you using ‘gtrendsR’ package?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, download data per day and define weeks in alignment with your measurements from the other dataset. Now Aggregate the Trends data. In case you are dealing with more than 3 months worth of data, consider to rescale your segments beforehand as described here: http://erikjohansson.blogspot.de/2014/12/creating-daily-search-volume-data-from.html
http://erikjohansson.blogspot.de/2014/05/daily-google-trends-data-using-r.html